# How to solve the "The message could not be sent because it has unresolved recipients." in Outlook for MacOs?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I keep getting the error msg "The message could not be sent because it has unresolved recipients." every time I sync my mail box:

[image]

I have tried different solutions like this one https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unresolved-recipients-message-prevents-email-to/4d79640c-60f6-49a8-9210-57c6e1c99fce with no luck.

Reading through the logs generated with log enabled option in Outlook brings no valuable information, I would need to know what recipient is really causing this (the error message could bring that along for my benefit, but hey, why would anyone think I would ever need that? :) ).

Any ideas?

MacOs 10.14.6
Outlook for Mac 16.28

Comment: Looks like some destination e-mail address is wrong formmated (like: missing domain, or just some name without full e-mail address) I would check all the destination recipient address and validate it for syntax) It the case for checking syntax `name@domain.com` (formatting syntax). Those messages seems to be on the outbox to be sent, stucked there because of that

Comment: Does viewing the email errors source give any details of the IP that wasn’t resolved? Worst comes to worse you can build new lists each time splitting the list in half to isolate the offender. There may also be a script utility to “finger” a list of email addresses to determine which address is not resolving to a destination. If the email is hosted internally, maybe changing the dns or looking at MX records could help debug.

Comment: @Prado please post it as an answer, I was able to find the Outbox folder (which I believed was no longer a thing in Outlook since I could not find it, I have not used Outlook for 10+ years now) and found the offending message. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some destination e-mail address is wrong formmated (like: missing domain, or just some name without full e-mail address)

I would check all the destination recipient address and validate them for syntax. It the case for checking syntax name@domain.com (formatting syntax).

This is not because non-existing final destination mail, is just technically wrong formatted e-mail syntax addresses

**Those messages seems to be on the outbox to be sent, stucked there because of that**

Check Outlook outbox for queued messages to fix that.